# Búsqueda en tiempo real visual Studio 2012

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc

Tengo la siguiente duda y soy un poco nuevo en esto, realizo un mantenimiento a un proyecto en asp.NET que trabaja con el patrón MVC resulta que cuando quiero realizar una búsqueda en tiempo real no me trae los datos, esto desde la solution del proyecto es decir desde mi archivo .sln

el mismo proyecto esta también en IIS y cuando lo abro de ahí si realiza la búsqueda en tiempo real.

No se si cuando subieron el proyecto en IIS el contenía extensiones o algún componente que le permitía realizar la búsqueda y no respaldaron la solution si no que la eliminaron.

cuando rescate el proyecto vi que le faltaban extensiones dll de la carpeta bin y algunas referencias y fui añadiéndosela y me los traje del proyecto que si servia y la aplicación funciona, pero esta parte de la búsqueda no funciona

Mi pregunta seria que extensión o componentes le hace falta a mi proyecto para que realice la búsqueda, esto porque ambos códigos que son de JavaScript están iguales utilice **Beyond Compare** para verificar que esten iguales.

**ANEXO LA FUNCION QUE REALIZA LA BUSQUEDA**

```
function doneTypingSearch() {
    $('.producto').autocomplete({        
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://api.ltl.com.ve/Rest/PublicService.svc/FindProducts",
                type: "POST", contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                crossOrigin: true,
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    Search: request.term,
                    ApiKey: "XXXXXXXXXX",
                    Count: 100,
                    StartIndex: 0,
                    StoreId: "A001"
                }),
                success: function( data ) {
           
                    var res = data;
                    var availableTags = [];
           
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.Products.length; i++) {
                        var principio = data.Products[i].ActiveIngredient != "" ? " - " + data.Products[i].ActiveIngredient : "";
                        var precio = data.Products[i].LastFullPrice != 0 ? " Precio: "+ (data.Products[i].LastFullPrice).toFixed(2) : "";
                        var opt = data.Products[i].Description + principio + precio;
                        availableTags.push({ label: opt, id: data.Products[i].Id, indice: i });
                    }
                    response( availableTags );
                },

            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            //alert(ui.item.label);
            //alert(ui.item.id);
            desbloquearGuardar();
            var sapCode = ui.item.id;
            $(this).prop("disabled", true);
            $($(this).nextAll("input[type=hidden]")).val(sapCode || "");
        },
        open: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
    }, function () {
        //var sapCode = $("#" + $(this).attr("list")).find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').attr("id");
        //$($(this).nextAll("input[type=hidden]")).val(sapCode || "");

        /* if ($(this).next("#searchresults").length > 0) {
        var sapCode = $($(this).next("#searchresults")).find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').attr("id");
        $($(this).nextAll("input[type=hidden]")).val(sapCode || "");
        }*/
    }, 300);
}
```

**ANEXO IMAGEN DEL PROYECTO ALOJADO EN IIS**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ANEXO IMAGEN DESDE LA SOLUTION**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La api a la que estas consultando que seria un servicio WCF, esta activo? porque me parece que te esta fallando la conexion a tu servicio donde dice Url en tu ajax

Comment: Si esta activo, de no estarlo no funcionaria del lado del IIS ya que hay esta publicado y funciona perfectamente y  como dije antes compare los archivos y están iguales.

Answer (score 0):

Logre conseguir que se viera tuve que configurar el archivo json del WebService puesto que allí se alojaban la clave ApiKey pues allí añadi una ApiKey a nivel local osea "localhost" ya que si ejecuto mi proyecto desde la solution es a nivel de mi maquina local. y desde el iis donde funcionaba ya estaba configurado el dominio